# Reason -nsert failed. First exception on row 1; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id:

Tags: salesforce, apex

I'm creating `OrderItem` records and getting error, cross reference identity:

> Reason -nsert failed. First exception on row 1; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id:

Any help with this reference?

```java
public class OrderItemCreate {

  public static void createOrderLine() {

    List<PriceBookEntry> priceBookList = new List<PriceBookEntry> ([SELECT Id, Pricebook2Id FROM PriceBookEntry]);

    Set<Id> priceBookSet = new Set<Id>();
    for (PriceBookEntry pb: priceBookList) {
      priceBookSet.add(pb.Pricebook2Id);
    }

    List<OrderItem> orderItemList = new List<OrderItem>();
    List<Order> orderList = new List< Order>([SELECT id FROM Order WHERE PriceBook2Id IN: priceBookSet]);

    for (Integer i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      OrderItem temp = new OrderItem();
      temp.PricebookEntryId = priceBookList.get(Math.mod(i, 2)).id;
      temp.OrderId = orderList.get(Math.mod(i, 2)).Id;
      temp.UnitPrice = 100;
      temp.Quantity = 1;
      orderItemList.add(temp);
    }

    if (orderItemList.size() > 0)
      insert orderItemList;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line :
 temp.PricebookEntryId = priceBookList.get(Math.mod(i, 2)).id;

should be :
 temp.PricebookEntryId = priceBookSet.get(Math.mod(i, 2)).id;

You were trying to put a PriceBookEntry id into a PriceBookId field.

I suggest you rename your variable PriceBookList to PriceBookEntryList.

Comment: Yes, but I cannot use get method with a set

Comment: The problem is that priceBookList contains PriceBookEntries, when PriceBookSet contains PriceBook ids : you are trying to put the id of the wrong type of object into temp.PricebookEntryId.   I suggest you first rename your variables correctly, then probably change the Set to List to implement the feature you are trying to provide.